# In the B737, does Trim Air require that air supply (by the APU, engines or external) is provided in order to operate?

Tags: boeing-737, bleed-air

Will switching ON the Trim Air switch in the B737 provide instrument cooling even without bleed air or external air supply?

Comment: Please be more careful with the tags. You created a new tag [b737] instead of using the existing [boeing-737] tag. Creating new tags should only be done when you are sure they are needed.

Comment: Also, consider that the subject & body of your question are phrased opposite each other. A "yes" answer to one would be a "no" to the other (which is why my answer says what it does, rather than starting with yes or no).

Comment: I started typing b737 and the tag appeared. How could I know it did not exist till now? Usually, when I type a tag that does not exist, the system does not let me post it. Apologies.

Answer (score 4):

The Trim Air switch will accomplish nothing without bleed air.

That switch exists when you have more temperature zones than packs -- in a 737-800, two packs & three zones (flight deck, forward cabin, aft cabin).  To make that work, the packs produce conditioned air at a temperature (i.e. the produce enough cold air) to satisfy the coldest temperature demanded, and then hot bleed air is added to the airflow going to the zones that don't need to be quite that cold.  In contrast, in a 737-700 (two packs & essentially two zones), the left pack delivers air to meet the demand of the flight deck temperature controller, and the right pack delivers air to satisfy the temperature control for the cabin.  Simple, and no trim air switch at all -- nothing to trim.

This all works when there is bleed air.  That's what powers the packs, and that's what's added to the pack output to adjust (trim) the temperature.  Without bleed air, there is nothing to trim (no pack output), and there's nothing to trim with.

If there isn't any pack output and no external air, then instrument cooling is provided by the recirc fans, only. (And you hope it isn't a hot, sunny day, because things can get warm pretty quickly in that condition, especially with an airplane full of people!)